# Can I pass a php variable to Html file in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

So I'm having quite a problem! I need to import a HTML file to a blade in Laravel, which I'm already doing! With this code:

```
<?php include ; ?>
```

I need to do it this way; for this project, I cannot transform the HTML files to blades.

But now comes a problem: my HTML files need to redirect me between them. For example if I have two HTML files, the first one needs to contain a redirect to the second one and vice versa. To do this, I need to pass a variable that contains that redirect to my HTML file: is that even possible?

I pass the collection that contains the argument to my blade already where I include the HTML File.

What I've tried:

I tried to pass the argument I need to the "href", imagine the argument is

```
$loop->iteration
```

Which it is, as I need to pass a int to my url, so I tried to :

```
href="{{$loop->iteration}}"
```

But it return me: exactly what I wrote in my url, so it doenst treat my argument as a php argument but as a string..

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Just edited it! ;)

Comment: You are including the html file on the same file blade file of this `href="{{$loop->iteration}}"` right? Can you add php variables to the html file?

Comment: @Claudio, No the href is included in my Html File, that I call in my blade! The question is if I can do it, and how, still didnt figure it out xD

Comment: You have blade files which include html (that contain blade tags) files and you want the html file to be treated as a blade file?

Comment: Not really, I have a blade file: Main.blade.php, in where I include a text.html file.
Inside de text.html file I have the href.

Comment: Have you tried including it like this `@include( 'html file' )`?

Comment: @Claudio, my html file isn't in my views folder, and the @ include only search for .blade.php files..